# Постраничный вывод данных

Tags: php

Помогите сделать постраничный вывод всех данных из баззы данных

Данные должны выводиться вот так картинка и текст ссылка

```
<?php 
include ("db.php"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT avatar,id,name FROM users WHERE login='$author'",$db); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);  

printf(
       "<a href='news.php?id=%s'>%s</a><a href='news.php?id=%s'><img alt='аватар' src='%s'></a>",
       $myrow['id'],
       $myrow['name'],
       $myrow['id'],
       $avatar
);
```

Хотя я хз мож не правильно сделал

Answer (score 2):

может так?

```
printf("<a href='news.php?id=%s'>%s</a><a href='news.php?id=%s'><img alt='аватар' src='%s'></a>",$myrow['id'],$myrow['name'],$myrow['id'],$myrow['avatar']);  ?>
```

Comment: А где соединение с базой данных и подключение к нужным данным